# Change HTML form input field text size

Tags: html, safari

I have html file like this one:

```
<p>
    Enter your first name and last name in the following form
</p>
<form>
    First name: <input  type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

and in CSS the text size of the p tag is set to 40px

I want to set the font size of two text boxes to be 40px too.

Comment: You can't have a form inside a paragraph.

Comment: @Quentin It's not preferred but it's technically OK as they are both block elements.

Comment: @iambriansreed — No, it isn't allowed … and browsers will terminate a paragraph at the start of a form.

Comment: HTML 4 says that paragraphs can only contain inline elements here: `<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->`

Comment: HTML 5 says that the content model of `p` elements is [*Phrasing content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#phrasing-content) (not flow content).

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for schooling me on HTML5. I think that's a new idea (Phrasing content) in HTML5. I am sure I read somewhere block elements can contain other block level elements.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing that out. I will correct it to avoid any non-standard browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements `input`, `textarea`, and `select` do not inherit styles like you might expect.

When defining your paragraph styles add the `input[type="text"]` selector:

```
p,
input[type="text"] {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

I will usually define them with my `body` font style.

Comment: thanks for the extra specialization in the CSS, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

So write a selector that matches them.

```
input { font-size: 40px; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked as expected. but I think @ambriansreed deserve the acceptance being more specific.